Anomaly in Updating React Array State
Updating state of array didn't work like expected!
I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe Game with this detail:
I have a state called gameBoardState (an 3x3 array) that contains the position of 'X' & 'O' with initial value of all 'null'.
**const initialGameBoard = [
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
];
**
export default function GameBoard({
  playerTurnHandler,
  onTurn,
  turnLogger,
  participant,
}) {
  **const [gameBoardState, setGameBoardState] = useState(initialGameBoard);**
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState('');
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
.
.
.
}

When the game is over there's a 'rematch' button that set the gameBoardState back to the initial state - which is all null.
Inside the onClick listener function, I copied the old value of the variable 'initialGameBoard' into a new const variable and then use this variable as the parameter of setGameBoardState(param). It didn't work :(
I also tried setGameBoardState(initialGameBoard). It didn't work too.
But when I initialized a new const variable inside the onClick function and directly use this variable inside setGameBoardState it did work!
Can someone explain to me why did it happen?
This is my complete code:
import { useState, useSyncExternalStore } from 'react';
import { WINNING_COMBINATIONS } from '../winning-combinations';
import GameOver from './GameOver';

const initialGameBoard = [
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
];

export default function GameBoard({
  playerTurnHandler,
  onTurn,
  turnLogger,
  participant,
}) {
  const [gameBoardState, setGameBoardState] = useState(initialGameBoard);
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState('');
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function checkWinner(actualGameboardState) {
    const numberOfCombinations = WINNING_COMBINATIONS.length;
    for (let index = 0; index < numberOfCombinations; index++) {
      const firstBlock = WINNING_COMBINATIONS[index][0]; //example = {row: 0, column: 0}
      const secondBlock = WINNING_COMBINATIONS[index][1]; //example = {row: 0, column: 1}
      const thirdBlock = WINNING_COMBINATIONS[index][2]; //example = {row: 0, column: 2}

      if (
        actualGameboardState[firstBlock.row][firstBlock.column] === null ||
        actualGameboardState[secondBlock.row][secondBlock.column] === null ||
        actualGameboardState[thirdBlock.row][thirdBlock.column] === null
      ) {
        continue; //if null, directly check the next combination
      }

      if (
        actualGameboardState[firstBlock.row][firstBlock.column] === 'X' &&
        actualGameboardState[secondBlock.row][secondBlock.column] === 'X' &&
        actualGameboardState[thirdBlock.row][thirdBlock.column] === 'X'
      ) {
        //do something
        setWinner(participant[0].toUpperCase());
      }

      if (
        actualGameboardState[firstBlock.row][firstBlock.column] === 'O' &&
        actualGameboardState[secondBlock.row][secondBlock.column] === 'O' &&
        actualGameboardState[thirdBlock.row][thirdBlock.column] === 'O'
      ) {
        //do something
        setWinner(participant[1].toUpperCase());
      }
    }
  }

  function selectSquareHandler(row, col) {
    const newGbState = [...gameBoardState];
    newGbState[row][col] = onTurn;
    setGameBoardState(newGbState);
    playerTurnHandler();
    turnLogger(row, col, onTurn);
    checkWinner(gameBoardState);
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
  }

  function rematch() {
    const initial = [...initialGameBoard];

    const initial2 = [
      [null, null, null],
      [null, null, null],
      [null, null, null],
    ];

    //setGameBoardState(initial); doesn't work! page isn't re-rendered
    //setGameBoardState(initialGameBoard) also doesn't work
    setGameBoardState(initial2);//works perfectly!
    setWinner('');
    setCounter(0);
    console.log(gameBoardState, winner, counter);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {(winner || counter === 9) && (
        <GameOver winner={winner} rematch={rematch} />
      )}
      <ol id="game-board">
        {gameBoardState.map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <li key={rowIndex}>
            <ol>
              {row.map((playerSymbol, colIndex) => (
                <li key={colIndex}>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => selectSquareHandler(rowIndex, colIndex)}
                    disabled={playerSymbol !== null ? true : false}
                  >
                    {playerSymbol}
                  </button>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ol>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </>
  );
}


Can you share the code that didn't work? "Inside the onClick listener function, I copied the old value of the variable 'initialGameBoard' into a new const variable and then use this variable as the parameter of setGameBoardState(param)". That sounds the same as the thing you're saying did work to me: " I initialized a new const variable inside the onClick function and directly use this variable inside setGameBoardState it did work"

Are you saying in one you did const newGbState = gameBoardState; which didn't work and then in the other you did const newGbState = [...gameBoardState]; which did work, and you are wondering why?

The arrays within your state have their own references. When you spread them, the references do not change. You'll need to create new references for your inner array as well. If you console.log(initialGameBoard) you'll notice the values change as you modify the board. An east way to do this is with structuredClone
const newGbState = [...gameBoardState];
// This is modifying your state!
// Do `const newGbState = structuredClone(gameBoardState)` instead
newGbState[row][col] = onTurn;

Here's a reproduceable example:
const initialGameBoard = [
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
];

initialGameBoard[0][1] = 1;
const x = [...initialGameBoard];

console.log(x[0][1]) // 1

x[0][0] = 0;
console.log(initialGameBoard[0][0]); // 0

@The Teabag Coder's solution will also solve your issue. I'm posting mine just to point out the root cause of the problem.

Agree with the two answers by @Mathew and @The.
const initial = [...initialGameBoard];

In the above statement,

The spread operator will spread the array elements correctly.
The array literal [] will create a new array successfully too.

However the issue over here is the type of the array elements. The array elements in this case are arrays itself. Therefore the the newly created array and the referenced array will have the same objects. The real impact of using the same objects with the new array is that it will lead to mutation of objects with which the React system does not comply. The objects in React state should be read-only - should not be modified. You will be able to know more about it from here.
The two solutions already given by them will work well. In addition to it, two of the alternatives solutions in functional approach may be as below:
map with spread
const newGbState = initialGameBoard.map((nestedArray) => [...nestedArray]);

map with slice
const newGbState = initialGameBoard.map((nestedArray) =>
  nestedArray.slice()
);

Thanks to @Nickparsons for his valuable comments

Thank you for your vote. Please leave your valuable feedback as well so that I may able to know the problem and perhaps I may be able to help you in a better way. You would have noted that while downvote even the platform asks everyone the same, and encourages to leave a feedback along with voting.

Not my dv, but both of the proposed solutions have superfluous components in them. With the first, you don't need the outer spread [... since .map() already returns a new array, so just const newGbState = initialGameBoard.map(... etc ...) is enough. With your second example, the nested map isn't really "mapping" and looks a little odd to use it just to create a new array reference, instead, you'd typically use .slice() for that rather than .map() (now JS doesn't need to invoke your inner map function each time either).

Hi, Thank you very much.I fully agree with you and I admit, i really missed some of the very basics. The code has now been amended based on your comments. @NickParsons
